SpringBoot Redis Increment upto a max 'n' value
I am using the following code to increment the value for a given key and return the value. Below code works fine, however, I want to only increment up to a max value  say 'n' and then reset the value, all while being a thread safe operation. Any help would be appreciated.
@Autowired
RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;


public long saveAndGetNextValue(){
return ops.increment("myKey:", 1);
}


If you have set your data in long in your provided key.
I hope this helps
long n= 999;
if((long)redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("yourKey") < n) {
redisTemplate.opsForValue().increment("yourKey", 1);
 }
else{
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("yourKey",1);
}


In a multithreaded environment isn't there a chance of multiple threads calling redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("yourKey",1) one after the other ?

Its not safe in multithreaded environment.
If multiple threads are calling concurrently it can be disturbed.
Instead of primitive long
You can use AtomicLong for achieving your purpose.
